# Do Apple Lossless tracks remain lossless when sent via Airplay to a 4th gen Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, airplay, compression, audio

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/does-lossless-audio-over-apple-airplay-have-preserved-audio-quality), from 2012, asks whether there is loss in the signal quality of an Apple-Lossless-encoded file when transmitted from a Macbook to an Airport Express.

I am wondering whether things are any different in 2016 when transmitting an Apple-Lossless-encoded file from a Macbook to a 4th gen Apple TV. Clearly Wifi is plenty able to transmit the file intact. With an HDMI connection to the TV and an Optical (audio) connection from the TV to the receiver, I should in principle be able to listen to an intact file.

1. Is it still the case in 2016 that lossless files go through an encode-decode cycle?
2. Is there any configuration that makes me say "use all available WiFi bandwidth, but let me listen to the original file"?
3. Is there any configuration that says "drop the video signal (for example, just display a static image of the cover of the album), and transmit the audio signal intact"?

Granted, this is not to be done for an extended period since the TV must remain on. Unlike the 3rd gen Apple TV, the 4th gen does not provide direct optical-out to the receiver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does lossless audio over Apple AirPlay have preserved audio quality?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/does-lossless-audio-over-apple-airplay-have-preserved-audio-quality)

Comment: This question here is way more specific and asking for an update to a four year old question. No duplicate, I would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about AirPlay Screen Mirroring from a Mac to an Apple TV. In that case, yes, you are loosing signal quality from compression-before-transmission and decompression-after-reception.

In particular, the audio part of the AirPlay Screen Mirroring is compressed using the AAC-ELD codec to ensure low-latency sound encoding. However, there is a signal loss involved.

Comment: By "I'm assuming" you're leading me to think that there is another way to Airplay to a 4th gen Apple TV. As I'm mentioning in the question, the 4th gen has no audio out, just HDMI out. This leads me to believe that the 4th gen does not have Airplay audio-only mirroring. But I'd love it if you can tell me this is incorrect.

Comment: There are others ways to AirPlay, yes. When you AirPlay a movie from your Mac (using an AirPlay compatible player ofcourse), a different protocol is using than when using screen-mirroring. In essence the Apple TV would then fetch the original video source directly instead of getting a re-encoded screen mirror image from the Mac. This also means that it receives the original audio part of the video source directly - so the audio part will not be reencoded for transport by the Mac.

Comment: That's very helpful to know. But it just struck me that we're still talking about two different issues. You're talking about video+audio. I'm talking about just audio. Now you can perfectly well reply that the 4th gen Apple TV was never meant to receive just music, and I already suspect that that was Apple's intention. I'd say that the issue is then closed. Those who want to listen to their lossless music collection must use a tethered connection. Airplay will not do.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have that idea. I can send audio to my 4g Apple TV without any problems (yes, just audio - not video). You'll need to connect your audio equipment via HDMI ofcourse.

Comment: I'm curious: during which years did it become pseudo-standard for receivers to receive video inputs?

Comment: I have no idea which year that debuted. However, it is common for receivers today to have many HDMI inputs for which the video is obviously passed through to the TV/projector, but the audio signal used by the receiver.

Comment: Yet it's not that long ago that I visited a couple of high-end audio stores and one gets asked there "are you looking for a stereo amplifier or a receiver?" with some level of indignation obviously reserved for someone who might utter the word "receiver". The idea being that the sound obtained from the former is not comparable with the one obtained from the latter. Perhaps Apple gathered that someone aiming for the absolute best sound they can get will in any case not consider inserting a wireless connection in any part of the chain. They'll hook their sound source directly to the amplifier.

Comment: High-end audio stores are known for logic defying arguments. They'll try to sell you a 500$ gold-plated ethernet cable over a 10$ cable claiming that it "sounds better", even though it is just transferring a digital signal. In the same way, a lossless codec sent wirelessly from a Mac to an AppleTV unit and via HDMI to the amplifier will sounds exactly the same as the same audio send losslessly over an optical S/PDIF cable. Indeed you can buy an audio extractor box that takes HDMI as input and outputs either coax or optical S/PDIF. Then you can connect to an old-fashioned amp without HDMI

Comment: One argument I heard in such stores is that nicer brands simply save their best for those who'll listen only. They do not provide the same level of acoustics to those who'll primarily be watching. Thanks for the hint to the existence of the "audio extractor boxes".

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. You're saying that manufacturers are making subpar products on purpose because their customers won't "listen enough". I don't buy it. However, if you said that many buy cheap receivers to be bundled with fancy televisions, and therefore they get crappy audio quality - I'll buy into that! If you want, you can certainly buy quality receivers - also with the possibility of HDMI input. If you preferred product does not come with HDMI input, then use an audio extractor box.